# How do I enable Live Syntax Checking in the Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, require, ace-editor

Ace Editor has [Live Syntax Checking](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Syntax-validation), which can check code as it's being typed for syntax errors.

I have a Rails 3.2 site with the Ace file included on each coding page. I added a require statement to the javascript to tell Ace where the worker file is, but it's still not working. How do I get Live Syntax checking to work?

Each coding page includes:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "ace-src/ace.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "ace-editor" %>
```

The Ace files are located in the ace-src folder. I aded this code to ace-editor.js:

```
require("ace/config").set("workerPath", "/assets/ace-src");
```

Comment: What error do you see? It works fine at http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/432/edit.

Comment: @auser, the highlighting works, but I want it to mark syntax errors, like when you type an error here: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about

Comment: Do the syntax error markers work for no language at all? Have you tried for JavaScript mode? Not all language modes have perfect syntax error marking support.

Comment: @yerforkferchips, that's correct, you can see it here: http://www.learneroo.com/modules/20/nodes/151

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntax checking is done via webworker which loads http://www.learneroo.com/assets/ace-src/worker-javascript.js file, but in your site that file seems to be empty. I only see `;` in it.
In the jsfiddle i showed earlier http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/432/edit, it didn't work because of cross origin restrictions on web workers (which i didn't notice since was running chrome with `--disable-web-security`), but thanks to latest Ace update, it works now.

Comment: link in above answer is outdated. Please update the link.