# ace editor syntax validation html+javascript

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, ace-editor, syntax-checking

I'm using Ace Editor, and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to live syntax check the HTML markup AND JavaScript code in the editor.

If I set "ace/mode/html" only HTML syntax is checked, so in the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <script>
            alert('This is a syntax error'+);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the JS syntax error is ignored by the editor.

Is there a way to tell to Ace Editor to check both HTML and Javascript?

Thank you very much!

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF [How do I enable Live Syntax Checking in the Ace Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995198)**

The question above explains how to execute syntax check HTML and JS in 2 separate editors, while I'm asking how to check them in the same one.

Comment: @R My question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995198

The question above explains how to execute syntax check HTML and JS in 2 separate editors, while I'm asking how to check them in the same one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use htmlhint, which has ace example running on thelanding page http://htmlhint.com/

Comment: This does not solve my problem, it checks only html and it doesn't check javascript

Comment: check jshint and csslint checkboxes at the side of the page

Comment: Indeed, it seems that it is checking both html and javascript when I check the jshint box.